# How can I link Go object file to a dynamic library?

Tags: c++, go, dll

I used [`swig`](https://github.com/swig/swig) to wrap `c++` in my `golang` project, I find that `golang` build can do separately:

1. generate object file
2. link the object file to binary file

like this(I get these from [makefile](https://github.com/swig/swig/blob/836a57190e85ba0b178782697af4d5dc1cb20a64/Examples/Makefile.in#L1854)):

```
go tool compile -pack -o runme.o runme.go
go tool link -linkmode external -extld "g++" -extldflags "-I/include/boost-0" -o runme runme.o
```

Anyway this works fine, but now I am facing a situation, I have to generate `c-share` library. I know that `go build` support [`-buildmode=c-shared`](https://golang.org/cmd/go/).

**So can I link the object `runme.o` file to `librunme.so`?**